# IntelliJ Indentation Formatting

Tags: intellij-idea, settings, curly-braces, auto-indent

So whenever I put a brace on a line like:

```
while(true)
{

}
```

it will auto indent like:

```
while(true)
        {

        }
```

I have no clue why it does this. It does not appear this way in my code style settings, where it looks just like the first indentation style, but it automatically does the second one anyway and doesn't recognize it as wrong.

In fact, I have an old java file where it doesn't do this, but I can't seem to make a new one that doesn't have this problem.

How do I fix this?

Comment: Please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with your code style and the sample file to reproduce.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set tab ident to 0 in setting 
[image]